# is http based on socket?

Tags: sockets, http

every connection to web server need a open port(default 80), so is it correct by regarding "http is based on socket"

or can I understand by this "TCP is a protocol, Socket implemented TCP, HTTP is based on TCP, so HTTP is based on Socket"?

Comment: @KorayTugay by searching "http is based on socket" I only got 2 result, it's weird, why people don't advocate this

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket, it explain well

Comment: @GuRu WebSockets are based over HTTP. There is nothing there that is relevant to this question.

Comment: HTTP is based on TCP, and sockets are the standard API for TCP (and UDP, and ...)

Comment: @EJP given wikipedia link, explain all over that u say. thanks

Comment: @GuRu I've said everything I need to say about it. If you think there's something there that's relevant, please quote it.

Comment: @EJP I appreciate bro, next time i will care about that. thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

HTTP is an application protocol, Socket is an operating system API. This means HTTP can not be based on sockets the same as cars are not based on gasoline.

**Relationship between Socket and HTTP:**

- Sockets **can be used to implement a HTTP** server/client since sockets can be used to implement any kind of TCP server/client and HTTP is an application layer protocol on top of TCP.
- **But** note that sockets **are not essential to implement HTTP**, i.e. you could use any other kind of API which manages to send network packets to implement it.

Comment: +1 for: But note that sockets are not essential to implement HTTP, i.e. you could use any other kind of API which manages to send network packets to implement it.